# Слушать порт в браузере

Tags: clientscript, tcp-ip, webbrowser

Какие существуют способы слушать порт в браузере клиента? на этот порт будут слаться данные другими серверами

Answer (score 1):

если нужно организовать асинхронный поток данных между браузером и сервером - рекомендую попробовать [вот это](https://github.com/sockjs/),
пользуюсь этим решением для браузерной игрульки, работает малость постабильнее, чем socket.io

Comment: А какой из проектов делает серверный сокет на клиенте?

Comment: что такое "серверный сокет на клиенте"?..  я дал свой ответ из-за уточняющего комментария автора - он р2р интересуется, и я предложил вариант реализации

Answer (score 0):

в браузере слушать ничего нельзя. это - over security.
если я, конечно, понял вопрос.

Comment: А как тогда с помощью флеша организуют p2p соединение?

Comment: А флеш - это не браузер. Это флеш. Можно к примеру и жава апплет прикрутить (товарищи взломщики только спасибо скажут:) )

Comment: В общем интересуют любые решения, встраиваемые в браузер